# Prevent Wordpress Automatic Logout

Tags: functions, login

I am using this function which is supposed to prevent wordpress from automatically logging me out. However, I am still being logged out every so often.

```
function my_logged_in( $expirein ) {
   return 31556926; // 1 year in seconds
}
add_filter( 'auth_cookie_expiration', 'my_logged_in' );
```

Is there another solution to this?

Comment: Have you verified in your browser dev tools that the cookie expiration is indeed being set?

Comment: Also, there are predefined macros for time lengths, e.g. `return YEAR_IN_SECONDS;`. Additionally, that filter also passes if the user checked `remember me`, but that functionality would be broken with that filter. Where is your filter placed? `functions.php`? A plugin? Is it itself ran on a hook? Have you verified that it gets called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we know by default WordPress keeps logged in for `48 Hours`. If we check "Remember me" while login then it will keep login for 14 Days.

If you want to set the logout timeout you can use this code as:

```
function wpset_change_cookie_logout( $expiration, $user_id, $remember ) {
    if( $remember && user_can( $user_id, 'manage_options' ) ){
        $expiration = 31556926;
    }
    return $expiration;
}
add_filter( 'auth_cookie_expiration','wpset_change_cookie_logout', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at your session.gc_maxlifetime in your php settings?
Also, some operating systems like Debian or Ubuntu have a crontab that flushes sessions. [More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865303/debian-based-systems-session-killed-at-30-minutes-in-special-cron-how-to-overri)